# Elastic Search Grouped Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing an array of key value pairs. The key is always a UUID and the value is a user entered value. I've been crawling through the documentation but I can't figure out exactly how to query in this scenarioExample schema:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "owner_id": 1,
  "values": [
    { "key": "k3kfa23rewf", "value": "the red card" },
    { "key": "23a2dd23108", "value": "purple balloons" },
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "owner_id": 1,
  "values": [
    { "key": "k3kfa23rewf", "value": "the blue card" },
    { "key": "23a2dd23108", "value": "purple balloons" },
  ]
}
```

I would like to query:

```
{ "term": { "owner_id": 1 },
{ "term": { "values.key": "23a2dd23108" }, "match": { "values.value": "purple" } },
{ "term": { "values.key": "k3kfa23rewf" }, "match": { "values.value": "blue" } }
```

So that the record with ID 2 is returned. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need here to use [nested documents](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html).

That way, you will be able to create [BoolQueries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html), with a Must clause with a TermQuery on owner_id and two must clauses with [nested queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) with Term and Match queries on `values.key` and `values.value`.

Does it help?

Comment: Can you please help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690293/how-to-match-an-array-value-by-its-key-in-a-key-value-pair-elasticsearch-array)? Thanks